# Setup Sharepoint search?

Tags: sharepoint, search, installation

For some reason my search in the sharepoint site does not work.

I have set up the SSP, the scopes, the crawls, everything but it still does not work

Can someone explain to me how to setup the search? Maybe I did something wrong in the process.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the simplest thing in the world to setup, as it's comprised of a number of components.
You need to check each one to determine where your problem is.
Start from the crawl, and work your way forward to the search production on the page.

So check the following:

- Check some servers have been setup to index pages. (You can see this under services on servers in the central administration pages.)
  Make sure they're all running correctly. (Not in a half started state.)
- Check your crawl log in your SSP to see if it is indexing anything.
  (Index different types of content, like file shares, web sites, and sharepoint itself. (check each one.)).
  (Note you need a special plugin to index PDF's.).
- Check your index is copied to the front end server where it is used.
  If it's not, it may be because this hasn't been configured, (Check Services running on servers again)
- Then check your site collection setup, and ensure you have a search site configured.
- Ensure the site collection search details are configured to use the search site.
- Finally check the user doing the searching actually has access to the content being indexed.

Doing all of that should give you some idea of where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bravax's answer its worth checking that you are not getting [stung by the local loopback check.](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and ended up using search server express which is free (see my answer from this link: [sharepoint 2010 foundation search not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158995/sharepoint-2010-foundation-search-not-working))

---

I have installed search server express 2010 on top of SPF which works great. it has additional features and work well with sharepoint foundation. her is a link for upgrade and configuration: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1086

You need to crawl the the contents source and add the website to it, then run full crawl to index data.