# sharepoint 2010 foundation search not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have installed SP 2010, but could not get the search to work. I have started search services, but it is still not working. Noticed that when I  search I get: We did not find any results for .... Any ideas. thanks!

Comment: You need to crawl the content before it can appear in search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed search server express 2010 on top of SPF. which works great. it has additional features and work well with sharepoint foundation. her is a link for upgrade and configuration: 
http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1086

You need to crawl the the contents source and add the website to it, then run full crawl to index data.